# What is the opposite of 'lockdown'?

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

The opposite of 'lock' is quite clearly 'unlock'.

But what is the single-word opposite of 'lockdown' ?

> The family were relieved when the time came to _________________.

EDIT : The comment is noted that this looks for a verb.

I would also accept a noun in the following sentence :

> The family were relieved when the time came for ________________.

Comment: Note that *lockdown* (as a single word) is a noun, so assuming its opposite is also a noun it wouldn't fit in your example sentence.

Comment: **Lifted**. The family was relieved when the lockdown was lifted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some people in the UK and India have been using the word "unlockdown" as the opposite of lockdown.

For example, see this [Sunday Times article](https://www.thetimes.co.uk/article/the-great-unlockdown-7wlbn3hdf)  on "The Great Unlockdown", referring to reversal of the lockdown that had been imposed due to COVID 19.

Comment: Accepted according to the Sunday Times reference and usage. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

With respect to lifting the lockdown of COVID-19, the news uses the word [**reopen**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reopen):

> [Merriam-Webster]
> : to open again
>   // school *reopens* in September
>   // The Bay Area’s ink industry has been on hiatus since March, and plans to *reopen* tattoo shops this week have been paused again after a recent surge in coronavirus cases.
> — Taylor Kate Brown, *SFChronicle.com*, "Bay Briefing: Raising the minimum wage amid the pandemic," 1 July 2020

In the example sentence in the question:

> The family were relieved when the time came to *reopen*.

It would most likely be followed by some kind of noun, such as *the economy* or *businesses*.

---

If talking about *social activities* specifically, a more common word to pair with it is [**resume**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/resume):

> **2** : to return to or begin (something) again after interruption
>     // She *resumed* her work.
>     // When official mourning was over, Soviet television *resumed* its normal pace.
>     — Bel Kaufman

With the example sentence again:

> The family were relieved when the time came to *resuming* social activities.

Answer (score 2):

Most recent uses of lockdown refer to the imposition of restriction of personal movement, and similar edicts.

I suggest that authorities ***let up*** on these restrictions (or even ***let up on*** them). It has a convenient mirroring on *lock down*.

> *informal (of something undesirable)* become less intense.
> Relax one's efforts.
> **let up on** *informal* Treat in a more lenient manner.
>
> — [Oxford/Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/let_up)

> The family were relieved when the time came to let up.

The noun form *lockdown* has its counterpart in ***let-up*** — this hasn't lost its hyphen yet.

> A pause or reduction in the intensity of something dangerous, difficult, or tiring
>
> [Ibid.](https://www.lexico.com/definition/let-up)

Comment: Up-voted. That was one of my own initial thoughts : that a lockdown is something enforced by authority. Therefore its opposite must relate to the _authority_ itself, not to that which is authorised.

Answer (score 2):

The opposite of lockdown is actually called freedom.  Like in your sentence above it is better said like this:
The family were relieved when the time came for freedom

Answer (score 1):

' Normalcy or Normality ', I think , could be the appropriate word in this context

Comment: While this answer is somewhat inelegantly worded, there is an important point behind it: the language has a word for a lockdown, because that is an unusual, noteworthy state of affairs, but one should not expect there to be an exact opposite for it, because there is nothing remarkable about non-lockdowns. Languages need specific words for specific abnormalities, but they don't always need specific words for the absences of specific abnormalities.